# Update details in the Detail view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a client detail view which has various information of the client i want to give an edit option to the use , so that they can edit the client.

urls.py

```
url(r'edit/(?P<pk>[0- 
9]+)/$',views.ClientInfoUpdate.as_view(),name='clientinfo'),
```

views.py

```
class ClientInfoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ClientInfo
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

clinetinfo_update_form.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% include 'update/form-template.html'%}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn- 
success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

[image]

detail.html

```
<td><small></small><a href="{% url 'update:clientinfo' client.id %}">Edit Info</a></td>
```

Comment: You can put `href` under link, right?  like `/edit/{{object.id}}/`

Comment: href link uder Edit info? The code for edit info :   <td><small></small><a href="{% url 'update:detail' client.id %}">Edit Info</a></td>

Comment: So this link is not working ? is that url correct ?. I can see url name is `clientinfo`.

Comment: the link is correct... but i suppose urls.py or views.py (ClientInfoUpdate(UpdateView)) there is some issue